# Dynamics CRM - Export User Access Audit

Tags: dynamics-crm

I've enabled User Access auditing in my CRM organization and can see user access logs in the Audit Summary View.  The problem is that I need to filter and export these to Excel to manipulate as I need to produce detailed analysis about the access times of users.

I cannot find an XRM Toolbox plug-in which does this, there are two which export Audit logs, but only (as far as I can tell), entity update / create logs, not user access.  I keep finding references on the web to a CRM Toolkit which was on Github years ago, but this has been archived and the executable is not longer available.

I've found c# source on the MSDN site to do this, but don't have the skills to compile this to get it working.

Does anyone know of a simple to install tool which will connect to my CRM org and export the access logs?  I'm even willing to pay for a good tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use XrmToolBox plugin named [User Audit Viewer](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/BDK.XrmToolBox.UserAuditViewer/), this will give you access time of users.

We can export the data by limiting resultset as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can export your data from your CRM at any time using the Export Data option. In the CRM, go to Settings / Data Management and open Export Data. Click the checkboxes to select the tables you wish to download then “Prepare Export”. This will bring you to a screen showing the status of your data export.